# why is it that <conio.h> doesn't work sometimes and using namespace std work in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying code at hackerrank but isn't working.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int b, int c)
{
    return b+c;
}

int main()
{
    int a,b,c,i,sum;
    cin>>a;
    for(i=1;i<=a;i++) 
    {
        std::cin>>b>>" ">>c; 
        sum=add(b,c);
        cout<<sum<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error : !cannot bind 'std::basic_istream::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream}' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream&&'
```

Comment: `why is it that <conio.h> doesn't work sometimes` Because `conio.h` isn´t a standard header. `why ... using namespace std work in c++.` Why not?  And how does the title and question belong together?

Comment: please use e.g. AStyle (free program) to fix the indentation.

Comment: Please update your title, as it stands it is not related to your question.

Comment: @CoryKramer has given the right answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this

```
std::cin >> b >> " " >> c;
```

You are trying to input a value into `b` and `c` which is fine, but this makes no sense

```
std::cin >> " "
```

That line should just be

```
std::cin >> b >> c;
```